# Bash sqlplus connection not from root

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, bash, sqlplus

i would like to connect from bash script and execute some procedures on ORACLE.

`su - oracle -c "sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect test/test
execute SCHEMA.PCG_TEST.P_PROCEDURE;
EOF"`

it works when do this on root, but i want to start script not from root.
How to do this ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what your *exact* problem is? What happens if you run this command as another user? Can you log on directly as oracle and run the script?

Comment: Also, check environment variables

Answer (score 0):

If you connect from the cron or something like it, probably sqlplus is not known.
So you have to set some environment variables or you have to call the entire path:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
```

That way it should work